# How to solve backward for an unknown given a condition in R?

Tags: r, function, math, optimization, linear-algebra

For a set of input (see below), when I run the following R code, I get two answers stored in `ncp`. But I want to know what should `df2` be such that the difference between these two answers in `ncp` (i.e., `abs(ncp[2] - ncp[1])`) is say `.15`?

So, everything else fixed, just what should `df2` be so that `abs(ncp[2] - ncp[1]) = .15`?  Can this be done in R?

```
alpha = c(.025, .975); df1 = 3; peta = .3   # The input

f <- function(alpha, q, df1, df2, ncp){     # Notice `ncp` is the unknown
  alpha - suppressWarnings(pf(q = (peta / df1) / ((1 - peta)/df2), df1, df2, ncp, lower = FALSE))
}

ncp <- function(df2){      # Root finding: finds 2 `ncp` for a given `df2`

 b <- sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),
      function(x) uniroot(f, c(0, 1e7), alpha = x, q = peta, df1 = df1, df2 = df2)[[1]])

 b / (b + (df2 + 4))
}
# Example of use:
 ncp(df2 = 108) # Answers: 0.1498627 0.4100823
                # What should `df2` be so that the difference between 2 answers is `.15`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `optim` and `optimize` functions in the `stats` package are a good way to handle this sort of problem.  `optimize` is simpler, dealing with a one-variable case.  Here's an example solution:

```
# Define a function that we want to minimise the output of
ncp_diff <- function(df2, target = 0.15){
  the_ncp <- ncp(df2)
  return(abs(abs(the_ncp[2] - the_ncp[1]) - target))
}

# try it out - how far out is df2 = 108 from our target value?
ncp_diff(108) # 0.1102

# find the value of ncp_diff's argument that minimises its return:
optimize(ncp_diff, interval = c(0, 1000)) # minimum = 336.3956

ncp(336.3956) # 0.218, 0.368
```

Note that while 336.3956 is *a* solution, it's not necessarily *the* solution.  You need to beware of local minima.  Dealing with that is out of the scope of a simple answer though.

Comment: There's a big literature on dealing with local minima issues but I don't know the best reference on dealing with it in a pragmatic way.  With only one unknown, I would start by plotting the whole parameter space against the result of ncp_diff() values to get a visual sense of if this is even a problem.